# jnlp unaivalable service exception

Tags: java, java-web-start

I am trying to use the FileOpenSerivce, but I always get an UnaivableServiceException regardless of whether I run it from Eclipse, or from my local webserver using the jnlp file.

I am using an unsigned jar, which from what I understand is ok.

I got a debugger connected, and when running under Webstart, everything seems to succeed just fine. I am attempting to get FileContents like so:

```
FileContents fileContents = fileOpenService.openFileDialog(null, null);
```

I never see a dialog, and fileContents is always null.

Thanks!

Comment: post the stacktrace displayed by java webstart

Comment: I don't get any kind of stacktrace from Webstart. My application just hangs. I get the UnaivableServiceException : unititialized from running it from Eclipse, which isn't running it under Java Webstart. So that makes sense. I get asked if I want the application to access files on my computer, and than nothing. No file dialog or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this whole thing was a threading problem. In my main class, MainFrame, my main method was

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    new MainFrame ();
}
```

I replaced it with this:

```
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainFrame();
        }
    });
```

And it all works fine now.